# Is it possible to create multidimensional-arrays from classes?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, multidimensional-array

Say you had code similiar to this:

```
#define maxX 80
#define maxZ 80

//Sector class
class Sect{
    ...
}

Sect sects[maxX][maxZ];
```

Would this create a plausible two-dimensional Sect array?

Answer (score 4):

It would create a 2-d array of `Sect` classes, yes. I'm not sure what you mean by "plausible", so I can't comment on that.

But consider:

- `std::array` and `std::vector`
- constants instead of macros

Comment: Why should I consider using `std::array` and could you show me an example of how I would use that in code?

Comment: @ShasaurAura an example is easy to find online, as well as arguments as to why using C++ containers should be preferred to C-style raw arrays or pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

This statement

```
Sect sects[maxX][maxZ];
```

creates a two-dimensional array of Sect's, of total size (number of Sect elements) `maxX * maxZ`. Valid indexes to your elements will be from `sects[0][0]` to `sects[maxX-1][maxZ-1]`. Trying to access data with indexes out of these bounds is invalid and will result in undefined behaviour.